# NSKeyValueObservation not working, Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, key-value-observing, swift4

How should I properly set up to receive notifications when the variable changes on the shared instance of the singleton?  Currently, the block is never fired.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    private var observer: NSKeyValueObservation?

    func configureKVO() {
        observer = MySingleton.shared.observe(\.shouldFetchDataFromServer) { (manager, change) in
            print("Changed: \(manager.shouldFetchDataFromServer)")
        }
        MySingleton.shared.shouldFetchDataFromServer = false
        MySingleton.shared.shouldFetchDataFromServer = true
    }
}

class MySingleton: NSObject {
    static let shared = MySingleton()
    @objc var shouldFetchDataFromServer: Bool = false
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Add the 'dynamic' keyword to the declaration of shouldFetchDataFromServer, and it should work.